# How to host a angular app correctly on cpanel?

Tags: angular

**Problem:**

I have developed a web application using angular I did the production build. After production build inside dist folder, there was a folder call frontend I rename that folder as an example as my domain is www.example.com so I uploaded that example folder in the public_html folder of my cpannel server after that I change the base URL in the index.html as /example/. Then I hit the URL https://example.com/example the sit was rendered successfully and I was able to route to all the components. But two images did not load correctly and API calls do not call. The errors for API calls like this.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My API calls like this `http://localhost:3000/api/somthing/`

I do not have any clue about this problem can someone give me help to solve this issue. Thank you